# When to save settings?

Tags: c#, java, serialization

Not the real question, but related: My app serializes it's settings  to isolated storage in main forms closing event. It works nice except some edge cases (Like 1% of shutdowns result in empty,broken file). Is this expected?

Now the real question:
What is the general pattern when dealing with serialization in C# or Java desktop apps? Should I wait for app's exit? Use an timer and save do serialization at certain intervals?

Comment: Saving just on exit is horrible. Nothing worse than configuring a program nicely and then keeping it running for hours/days and then losing all settings because of a system crash etc.

Comment: A downside to saving on change is if your application could be misconfigured in such a way that it cannot be restarted.  That might argue for either multiple named sets of parameters or a "last known good" set.  Otherwise, I concur with the Wisdom of SO and the Official Microsoft Motto: Save early, save often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save whenever the settings change, unless you have high volume.

The most important issue here is corrupted files. You should save to a temporary file and when the serialisation is complete you should then swap the files in a quick, atomic operation. If anything goes wrong you can read the old copy of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest saving settings as they change as being the most robust solution, as well as potentially saving on exit. Unless you are in some crazy situation where settings are changing at a rapid pace (but that seems unlikely).